# How to Add my link in Contact module in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I am working with Web development using Drupal 7.

I added the Contact module in my Site.

I want to add one more field in between the Contact Module (Marked in the image).

I am new for Drupal and PHP.

Help me to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Maybe switching to webform module. There for sure you can precisely define form fields as you like plus many more useful features:
https://www.drupal.org/project/webform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are new to Drupal, I'd recommend you [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) contrib module. It is really easy and configurable.

Instead, if you would like to use the contact form itself. There what might be helpful:

- [Create drupal 7 custom modules](https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7). ([Tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/1074360))
- Then, learn how to [create your own hook](https://www.drupal.org/node/2302845).
- Then, use [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), to alter the contact form to add more fields (using [drupal form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7)) and handle submitting new fields.